# Merging two XML variables - please help!

Tags: sql-server, join, xml

I am using SQL Server Management Studio 17.9.1 with SQL Server 2016 Service Pack 2 (SP2).

There is no table structure to show, just two **XML variables** that contain XML, as shown below:

```
DECLARE @A XML = '
<ManageByCountry>
  <CountriesAllowed>
    <Country name="United States" countrycode="US" />
    <Country name="Canada" countrycode="CA" />
  </CountriesAllowed>
</ManageByCountry>
',
@B XML = '
<ManageByCountry>
  <CountriesAllowed>
    <Country name="United Kingdom" countrycode="GB" />
    <Country name="Puerto Rico" countrycode="PR" />
    <Country name="France" countrycode="FR" />
  </CountriesAllowed>
</ManageByCountry>
';
```

I am looking for a statement that would output this:

```
<ManageByCountry>
  <CountriesAllowed>
    <Country name="United States" countrycode="US" />
    <Country name="Canada" countrycode="CA" />
    <Country name="United Kingdom" countrycode="GB" />
    <Country name="Puerto Rico" countrycode="PR" />
    <Country name="France" countrycode="FR" />
  </CountriesAllowed>
</ManageByCountry>
```

My knowledge of querying XML isn't that good and I have no idea where to search first on how I could achieve this.

Comment: Do you think mentioning your DBMS and showing the corresponding table structure might be helpful?

Comment: @mustaccio, you are correct, thank you for pointing this out. I will do so in the future.

Comment: You should do so _today_ (by editing your question) -- it will help future readers to find this question and the useful answer by keywords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [query()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/query-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15) to get the Country nodes from both variables and use [for xml path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) to rebuild the XML.

```
select @A.query('/ManageByCountry/CountriesAllowed/Country'),
       @B.query('/ManageByCountry/CountriesAllowed/Country')
for xml path('CountriesAllowed'), root('ManageByCountry');
```

Comment: Thank you Mikael for this solution, this is EXACTLY what I was looking for. I need to learn more about syntax relating to XML.